# Не обновляется $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

Tags: php

При каждом запросе страницы в `useragent` хранится одно и тоже значение, которое было впервые получено, например, сразу после установки скрипта, скрипт возвращает `useragent` клиента, но при повторном запросе с другого обозревателя `useragent` возвращает предыдущее значение. Переменная обновляется после любой правки скрипта.
Вопрос как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такого  не может быть. Скорее всего Вы выводите просто его после сабмита или другого экшена.

Comment: Имеете ввиду, после отправки данных формы? Если да, то формы на страницы нету...

Comment: Все разабрался, дело в CMS - она кешировала результат скрипта. Спасибо за внимание к проблеме!